# When my iPhone app auto rotates, my camera orientation is wrong

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I looked through a lot of documentation. I can't find an answer at all.

Every time I rotate my camera my UI rotates obviously but then my camera stays with that rotation.

It's like the coordinates are local still instead of facing global north.

What else can I look up?

```
import UIKit
import AVFoundation

class scannerViewController: UIViewController   {
    
    var session      : AVCaptureSession!
    var input        : AVCaptureInput!
    var previewLayer : AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer!
    var camera       : AVCaptureDevice!
    
    
    
    @IBOutlet weak var cameraPreview: UIView!
    
    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)
        
        
        session = AVCaptureSession()
        
        camera = AVCaptureDevice.default(for: AVMediaType.video)
        
        input = try? AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: camera!)
        
        session.addInput(input)
        previewLayer = AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer(session: session)

       
        cameraPreview.layer.addSublayer(previewLayer)
        
        
        DispatchQueue.global(qos: .userInitiated).async {
            self.session.startRunning()
            
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.previewLayer.frame = self.cameraPreview.bounds
                
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Try setting the [AVCaptureVideoOrientation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avcapturevideoorientation)

Comment: when i read https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avcaptureconnection, and https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avcapturevideoorientation.... it says that that is an enumeration.... which i have read through the docs on swift and i believe it is not an immutable object so i can change it .... also if i just type AVCaptureVideoOrientation.portrait i am pretty sure that doesn't mean anything

Comment: how do i set AVCaptureVideoOrientation

Comment: You set it on your `previewLayer.connection`. `if let connection = previewLayer.connection { connection.videoOrientation = ... }`

Comment: i am reading these doc pages thouroughly is it me or are they not very good... am i missing something how would i have known that

Comment: Yeah, it's tough. Lots of clicking and reading. I usually try to see if they have any sample apps available when I'm learning something new.

Comment: im trying to read about the connection on the avcapturevideopreviewlayer and i see that videoorientation is just a getset var in the connection of the input for that layer ... so i typed .               previewLayer.connection?.videoOrientation = AVCaptureVideoOrientation.portrait
and it did nothing